# C++ Cast operator overload

Tags: c++, types, casting, typecasting-operator

I have a class with a single int member such as:

```
class NewInt {
   int data;
public:
   NewInt(int val=0) { //constructor
     data = val;
   }
   int operator int(NewInt toCast) { //This is my faulty definition
     return toCast.data;
   }
};
```

So when I call the `int()` cast operator I'd return `data` such as:

```
int main() {
 NewInt A(10);
 cout << int(A);
}
```

I'd get 10 printed out.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [user-defined cast or conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) has the following syntax:

- `operator conversion-type-id`
- `explicit operator conversion-type-id`   (since C++11)
- `explicit ( expression ) operator conversion-type-id`    (since C++20)

**Code** [[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/FXoZAk)]:

```
#include <iostream>

class NewInt
{
   int data;

public:

   NewInt(int val=0)
   {
     data = val;
   }

   // Note that conversion-type-id "int" is the implied return type.
   // Returns by value so "const" is a better fit in this case.
   operator int() const
   {
     return data;
   }
};

int main()
{
    NewInt A(10);
    std::cout << int(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If I changed int for float in the definition, would it automatically cast it to float?

Comment: @darkstylazz It would support implicit casts to `float` in that case. Whether such a cast would actually happen depends on the use case of course.